# How do I change two letters closest to a string and one letter immediately after a string using Notepad++?

Tags: notepad++

I have a list of emails, and I want to change the two letters before "@" and the first letter after "@" using Notepad++.

For example:

```
username@yourdomain.com
```

becomes

```
userna**@*ourdomain.com
```

Comment: Just an obvious remark, the concrete example you gave shows how useless this pattern would be to anonymize email addresses. It’s usually better like x******@y***.com

Comment: @eckes would that even be possible in N++?

Comment: @WELZ Yes but its more work, a half working sample would `(.)[^@]*@([^.]).*(\.[a-z]+)` use 3 capture groups which you can address in the replace with string: `\1***@\2***\3` - uses a fixed number of mask characters but this is actually good.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

#### I want to change the two letters before "@" and the first letter after "@"

- Menu "Search" > "Replace" (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd>)
- Set "Find what" to `..@.`
- Set "Replace with" to `**@*`
- Enable "Regular expression"
- Click "Replace All"

  [image]

Before:

```
username@yourdomain.com
```

After:

```
userna**@*ourdomain.com
```

---

#### Further reading

- [How to use regular expressions in Notepad++ (tutorial)](http://docs.notepad-plus-plus.org/index.php/Regular_Expressions)
- [Notepad++: A guide to using regular expressions and extended search mode](http://markantoniou.blogspot.co.uk/2008/06/notepad-how-to-use-regular-expressions.html)
- [Regular Expressions Tutorial](http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html)
- [RegExr: Learn, Build, & Test RegEx](http://regexr.com/)
- [regex101: Online regex tester and debugger](https://regex101.com/)
- [RegExper: Regular Expression Visualiser](https://regexper.com/)

Comment: I'd say it should be `.?.@.` as there might not be two characters before @.

Comment: @n0rd The question specified two characters, but you are correct if there is only one.

Answer (score 10):

You can do this by using a regex search/replace.

At the bottom, select Regular Expression.

In the Search for entry, you type in: `..@.`
In the Replace with, you type in `**@*`

Then press the button <kbd>Replace All</kbd>

This works because Regex searches will only replace if its search criteria matches exactly. The match is explained as follows:

`..@.` There are 3 dots and an `@`:

- `@` has no special meaning in regex so it means a literal @.
- `.` means any character, exactly once. By writing `..` it means 2 characters of any kind, as long as there are 2 characters.